# WHERE clause comparing non-empty field to null

Tags: sql

I am facing a weird issue here with my sql statment. Maybe it's something stupid and I can't catch it.

```
SELECT appointment.patient_id,
       patient.notes,
       patient.first_name,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(27), appointment.start_time, 100),
       patient.email_address
FROM   appointment,
       patient
WHERE  Day(appointment.start_time) = 06
       AND Month(appointment.start_time) = 06
       AND Year(appointment.start_time) = 2013
       AND appointment.appointment_type_id != ''
       AND appointment.location_id != ''
       AND appointment.patient_id = patient.patient_id
       AND patient.email_address != '';
```

The above query returns 3 records. The value of 'notes' field is NULL in all 3 records.
If I add a criteria `patient.notes != '1 Reminder'`, shouldn't it return the same resultset? When I try it, it returns zero records. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Step #1 is writing code (or SQL) so others (and yourself) can read it.

Comment: Now, compare: `select * from (select NULL as a) x where x.a ~op~ NULL` - replace `~op~` with `=`, `<>`, `IS` and `IS NOT`. What are the results?

Comment: thanks for your reply. If i write a test sql like, "select * from patient where notes != '1 Reminder'", it works fine. That tells me that the syntax is fine. Am i right?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!)

Comment: Try to be informative with your question title. Thanks! (And feel free to re-edit if you have a better one, but 'Weird issue' doesn't help future visitors find the solutions we're giving you!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your expectation is wrong.  ANY comparison to `NULL` is NULL (treated as false) with the exception of `IS NULL`.

So, `patient.notes != '1 Reminder'` is false, just as `patient.notes = '1 Reminder'` is false.  You can handle this by doing:

```
coalesce(patient.notes, '') != '1 Reminder'
```

Comment: thanks. So how should i write this condition? Basically I want all the records who DOESN'T have '1 Reminder' in notes field. It can be null or any other value.

Comment: @user2443689 . . . See the last line in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. Sorry I didn't see the last line before. I am new to stackoverflow. Really appreciate your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

A != operator will not resolve to true on a NULL value.  To get records that other than "1 Reminder", **including** NULLs, use "patient.notes != '1 Reminder' or patient.notes IS NULL".

Comment: Thank you. That worked too. I also tried "coalesce(patient.notes, '') != '1 Reminder'", Gordon's courtesy, which also did the job.

Comment: I suggested this method because it may be more portable.  Some databases (namely Oracle) treat the empty string as a NULL.  So ''='' is false in Oracle, though it's true in other DBs.